# How can I implement a custom mapping model for Core Data?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, core-data-migration

I've added a new entity (Site) to my Core Data Model, and a relationship to my old entity (Notification) pointing at Site. What I need to do is populate the new entity with a single object (the values for the attributes of the new object are in User Defaults right now), and then assign all of the old objects to the variable representing the relationship.

The notifications variable on the Site object is one-to-many and optional. The site variable on the Notification object is one-to-one and required.

My new object looks like so:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Site : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *url;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *accessKey;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *secretKey;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *notifications;

@end
```

The old object has a new 'site' attribute:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "Site.h"


@interface Notification : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *created;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *isRead;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *message;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *notificationId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *url;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *urlMarkRead;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Site *site;

@end
```

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Comment: You want to move `url`, `accessKey`, `secretKey` from `Notification` into `Site`?

Comment: No. I have url, accessKey, and secretKey in Shared User Defaults and want to create a new site object based on those values. The problem is, I can't load up the new model without first performing a migration, and I can't do a lightweight migration, either.

Comment: I edited my original post to include that information.

Comment: Please mark the question as answered, if it is. Thanks.

Comment: Would this be an update to an existing app? If not, you only need to update the XCDataModel, and delete the app from your device (or reset settings on the simulator) then reload it. If it IS an update, I would recommending following Daniel Eggert's advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a manual migration. It's going to be some work for you to code that up, but it'll solve your problem.

Take a look at the *Core Data Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide*. There you'll find *The Migration Process* with a subsection called *Custom Entity Migration Policies* which describes your situation.

You need to create a subclass of `NSEntityMigrationPolicy`.

Comment: Thanks. I just ended up clearing my data and starting over from scratch with the new version of my model, but this info will be useful in the future.